# Value Error: too many vaules to unpack when calling Python requests

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to use Python requests to send put rest api,

```
def put(payload):
  url = "https://server"
  headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
  
  response = requests.put(url, headers=headers, data=payload) 
  return response.status_code
```

My payload is json string (by using pyspark function to_json on a json object) like:

```
{"category":[{"coding":[{"code":"mycode"}]}],"code":{"coding":[{"code":"5","display":"test"}]}}
```

But I am getting an error saying PythonException: ValueError: too many values to unpack on the line 16 (which is requests.put) when I call it in a map function

```
df.select("payload").rdd.map(lambda x: put(x)).collect()
```

I tried to use json=payload, but I got Bad Request from the status_code.

Can anyone tell me what could be wrong?

Comment: The error may same, but I have different issue than the "dup" one.

Answer (score 1):

You forgeto to unpack values inside lambda function. This is the correct one:

```
df.select("payload").rdd.map(lambda x: put(x[0])).collect()
```

Comment: Are you sure payload is string?

Comment: Yes. It turned out my payload is not valid for the rest api. Thank you. It worked now.  Another quick question, do you happen to know how to merge the response back to the df? I like to know for each row, if the request is succeed or not.

Comment: from pyspark.sql.types import StringType  ;
    from pyspark.sql.functions import udf;

    putUdf = udf(put, StringType());

    df = df.withColumn("response", putUdf(df.payload));

This would create a new column called response and fills in with output from put method